# Create red Polyline around point symbol

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, nuget

I am using the Esri.ArcGISRuntime 100.5.0 NuGet package with C#.

I want to add something like a border around a point symbol. So I get the geometry of the symbol (this can be a circle, square, etc.) which is a Polygon geometry.

Based on this geometry I want to create a simple red Polyline.

I tried the following, but I only get a filled rectangle:

```
var solidStrokeSymbolLayer = new SolidStrokeSymbolLayer(solidStrokeSymbolLayer.Width, Color.Red)
{
    IsColorLocked = true,
    IsEnabled = true
};
var polygonSymbol = new MultilayerPolygonSymbol(new List<SymbolLayer>
{
    solidStrokeSymbolLayer
});
var vectorMarkerSymbolElements = new List<VectorMarkerSymbolElement>
{
    new VectorMarkerSymbolElement(geometry, polygonSymbol)
};
var vectorLayer = new VectorMarkerSymbolLayer(vectorMarkerSymbolElements)
{
    IsEnabled = true,
    IsColorLocked = true
};

var pointSymbol = new MultilayerPointSymbol(new List<SymbolLayer>
{
    vectorLayer
})
{
    Size = 30d
};
```